# telerik mvc grid rebind pass array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, jquery, telerik-grid

Hi i have array of values and i need to pass it as argument for telerik mvc grid rebind in client side. My code:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push("one");  arr.push("two");      
var grid = $('#TreeTermGrid').data('tGrid');
grid.rebind({ItemsArr: arr });
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetTList(List<string> ItemsArr)
{        
//but i got one element with data "one,two"
}
```

How can do it correct?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public ActionResult GetTList(string ItemsArr)
{        
    string [] items = ItemsArr.Split(',');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer i just think to do that

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the results of the array compatible with the binding mechanism in ASP.NET MVC, we need to use the ‘traditional’ setting in $.ajax(). The rebind function using $.ajax() to call the controller and you could try this to enable ‘traditional’ globally:

```
$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```